# Getting http-session from a child thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I'm using spring framework and here's the piece of code I'm using to retrieve the `HttpSession` object:

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr;
try {
    attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
            .currentRequestAttributes();
} catch (Exception e) { }
HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession(false);
```

The thing is [RequestContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html)

> Holder class to expose the web request in the form of a ***thread-bound***
>   RequestAttributes object.

therefore it won't be seen outside of the thread created by the container for handling the request. Is there a way to retrieve the session in some child thread?

Comment: Nope as that would be quite a security breach...

Comment: @M.Deinum So, any session is a thread-bound object. But is that specified somewhere in the `servlet API` documentation or somewhere else? I've just never thought about accessing tot the session from multiple threads...

Comment: Nor should you want that. Imagine you have a shopping cart in your session, and anyone was allowed to modify the session and add things to your cart... I guess you wouldn't be happy if that happened... Imagine your security credentials are stored in the session (spring security does) and anyone could access it (a badly designed framework could put your password there)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. In the Servlet API, the session is a property of the request object. Therefore, if you don't have a request, which of the many existing sessions would you retrieve?

Comment: Thanks much! BTW, couldn't you cite a relevant section from the specification if you know where it is...?